# How can I add a register link on the sharepoint teamsite indexpage

Tags: c#, sharepoint

How can I add a register link on the sharepoint teamsite indexpage and make this link visible only when a user is not connected?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using FBA for authentication users. You can use ASP.NET login control to achieve that.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" FormatString="Hello {0}" />
</LoggedInTemplate>
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server">
    </asp:Login>
</AnonymousTemplate>
```

Hope that helps.

NLV